SQL Server 2022 Express: Missing protocols for instance in Network Configuration
I installed an instance but there is no option for Protocols for <instance_name>. In the image it only shows two options from another software (TIA PORTAL, maybe) and show none of the installed instances.
How do I fix this since I really need to enable TCP/IP for my instance to be connected remotely. I already configured mixed mode authentication, allowed remote connection to instance and opened port 1433 in firewall.


Do you have another menu item under 'Azure Extension For SQL Server' named 'SQL Server Network Configuration'? I just installed SQL Server Express 2022 edition. I see 'Protocols for SQLEXPRESS' under 'SQL Server Network Configuration.'

Unfortunately there's nothing under Azure Extension For SQL Server

Can you try to open mmc.exe and open this file C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager16.msc? I want to make sure you are opening the right file in case you have a different version installed on the same host.

I tried opening that file from mmc.exe and it shows the error: MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might have not been installed correctly

I suggest you resolve that issue first and then try again. There are a few options here.

You do not see the complete list of items on the left side because the SQL Server Configuration Manager Snap-in is not installed correctly or is corrupted.
If installed correctly, you will see the SQL 2022 SQLEXPRESS edition Protocols under 'SQL Server Network Configuration'.
In the example below, this SQL 2022 Express Edition is installed as a named instance (SQLEXPRESS):


It is incredibly simple for me to solve the "could not create snap in" by following these steps:

Go to path "C:\SQL2022\Express_ENU" (can differs a little bit on different version)
Run SETUP.EXE as administrator then navigate to Maintenance. Choose Repair, specify one instance,follow the instruction and wait until the process is done

This should fix the "could not create snap in" error in mmc.exe when opening SQLServerManager16.msc
I still cannot fix error missing Protocols for <instance_name> but will update as soon as possible.
